# bxSlider loading overlay on IE10 Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10, bxslider

I have implemented the bxSlider plugin in my site. The slides are div's, not images.
Somehow, on Windows Phone, I get this loading overlay (see picture), which doesn't disappear. I can still access the links in the div "behind" the overlay and use the prev/next navigation. But I can't get rid of this overlay! Works on every other browser. Any thoughts?

it's a white box (z-index seems to be pretty high) and in it there is a loading gif (stripes arranged in a circle).

[image]

Comment: i had the same issue. i solve it with css. the whole element H-A-S to be `direction:ltr;`

Comment: Hey Johnny, thanks for your reply. What do you mean, the whole element? I tried assigning direction:ltr; to bx-wrapper and the ul bxslider element, nothing changed...

Comment: im sorry. i did only on the wrapper and it worked but im not sure why that why i did not post it as answer, but as comment. perhaps do a js workaround to hide that specific element if you see that the useragent is windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but windows phone responds better when you delay the function that calls the bxSlider.  One way of doing this is to wrap bxSlider in a function and then give it a timeout in the `$(document).ready` function. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(yourFunction,500);
});
```

if you want to do this just for windows phone then you could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("windows phone") != -1) {
    setTimeout(yourFunction,500);
    }else{
     yourFunction();
    }
 });
```

There is probably a nicer way to do it, but this seems to work.